# Does the Juggling algorithm support right rotation?

Tags: algorithm

I know that juggling works for left rotation. Does right rotation fit for juggling algorithm ? If so, then what has to be modified for it to work for right rotation?

Left rotation using juggling algorithm

[Reference taken from 3rd method on the below link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-program-for-array-rotation-2/amp/)

```
/*Function to left rotate arr[] of siz n by d*/
```

> void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n) { int i, j, k, temp; for (i =
>   0; i < gcd(d, n); i++) { /* move i-th values of blocks */ temp =
>   arr[i]; j = i; while(1) { k = j + d; if (k >= n) k = k - n; if (k ==
>   i) break; arr[j] = arr[k]; j = k; } arr[j] = temp; } }

Pls help me whether it supports or not

Comment: Simply replace any read/write to `arr[x]` by a read/write to `arr[(n-1) - x]`.

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica thanks a ton. it is working. If you add it as answer I'll accept it and close it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach to convert algorithms like this is to check if there any symmetry (or other homomorphisms) between what you have working and what you want.

Here, you can observe that flipping the array direction, running the algorithm, and flipping back would work. So, you can simply replace any read/write to `arr[x]` by a matching read/write to `arr[(n-1) - x]`

Comment: Wow Excellent Answer